How can I implement dependence between locally defined variables in With?
I have a procedure that randomly selects a list element and compares the element value to the value of its position. If a condition is met, the element is replaced. The following works
L = RandomInteger[10, {10}]
i = RandomInteger[{1, 10}]
j = L[[i]]
L = If[i < j, ReplacePart[L, i -> L[[j]]], L]

but I want to write it as a function. I tried this:
L = RandomInteger[10, {10}]
M = With[{i = RandomInteger[{1, 10}], j = #[[i]]}, 
   If[i < j, ReplacePart[#, i -> #[[j]]], #]] &
M[L]

The With function doesn't seem to be able to handle j depending on i. I tried to nest Withs like this:
L = RandomInteger[10, {10}]
M = With[{With[{i = RandomInteger[{1, 10}]}, j = #[[i]]]}, 
   If[i < j, ReplacePart[#, i -> #[[j]]], #]] &
M[L]

and also tried switching one of the Withs to Module but neither option runs. How can I do this?

The syntax is With[{variable_assignment}, expr]. A variable assignment is either of the form symbol = value (Set) or symbol := value (SetDelayed); it cannot start with With. However expr may be a With statement (or contain one), and it may depend depend on outer With expressions.

Instead of using "With", you may use "Module" like: M := Module[{i, j},     If[(i = RandomInteger[{1, 10}]) < (j = #[[i]]),      ReplacePart[#, i -> #[[j]]], #]] &

L = RandomInteger[10, {10}]
M = With[{i = RandomInteger[{1, 10}]}, 
   With[{j = #[[i]]}, If[i < j, ReplacePart[#, i -> #[[j]]], #]]] &
M[L]

